# Can only see 2GB of 4GB on 2.6.26-1-xen-amd64 debian 5, Dell PowerEdge 860

Tags: linux, memory, 64-bit, debian, xen

Any suggestions? Adding mem=4G to grub doesn`t help.

```
free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2538496     299684    2238812          0       7380      34328
-/+ buffers/cache:     257976    2280520
Swap:      9896000          0    9896000


uname -a
Linux 2.6.26-1-xen-amd64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 13 21:39:38 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux

grub> displaymem
displaymem
 EISA Memory BIOS Interface is present
 Address Map BIOS Interface is present
 Lower memory: 640K, Upper memory (to first chipset hole): 3072K
 [Address Range Descriptor entries immediately follow (values are 64-bit)]
   Usable RAM:  Base Address:  0x0 X 4GB + 0x0,
      Length:   0x0 X 4GB + 0xa0000 bytes
   Reserved:  Base Address:  0x0 X 4GB + 0xa0000,
      Length:   0x0 X 4GB + 0x60000 bytes
   Usable RAM:  Base Address:  0x0 X 4GB + 0x100000,
      Length:   0x0 X 4GB + 0x300000 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel must be 32bit without PAE, enable PAE or switch to a 64 bit kernel.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that your xen domU servers are using 2GB and a dom0 only shows you usable memory excluding what is allocated to a domU.